# Create List from List of Key-Values

Tags: python, json, firebase

Given the JSON structure below, I want to grab all the data from an item, then pull one of the values for `link` out randomly.

Using `random` - I am familiar with grabbing a random value from a list. Where I'm stuck is how to make a list from the list. See code below JSON.

```
Item0:
    0
    caption: "caption 0"
    link: "www.item0.com"
    type: "type0"

    1
    caption: "caption 1"
    link: "www.item1.com"
    type: "type1"
```

PYTHON:

```
chosen_item = "Item0"
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://app.firebaseio.com')
result = firebase.get(chosen_item, None)

if result: 
  for i in result: 
    result_link = (i['link'])
    print result_link
```

the `if-statement` loops through and returns the `link`'s in the item as `unicode` type. How do I make a list from this? ( `result_link` )

Answer (score 2):

```
chosen_item = "Item0"
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://app.firebaseio.com')
result = firebase.get(chosen_item, None)

if result: 
  links = []
  for i in result: 
    links.append(i['link'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result_links = [x for x in result['link']]
```

If you need to use the index numbers, try this:

```
result_links = []
i = 0
for item in results:
    result_links.append(item[i]['link'])
    json_index +=1
```

Comment: thanks... only problem is I guess the Firebase array-numbering is applicable - I've gotten this error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: Yeah the numbers at the start of the entries are not negligible.  You need to access it with results[i]['link]

Comment: For some reason when I used the `result_links = []` solution (needing to access through `i`... I received only the first link, but multiple times.